# Pipeline trigerring Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline which creates 3 release/branch on 3 repositories.
Let's call them A B C

Then after creation of branches another pipeline is triggered:
Build of our application.

[image: Branches names]

As you can see it use only one of new branches.
A - Ops repo with pipelines
B - application repo where new release/* branch trigger a build

I would like to made it use use both RC branches with the same names

Comment: Did you use the [repository resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-repositories-repository?view=azure-pipelines) to trigger the new pipeline? May i know if the release branch name is dynamic or static? And could you please elaborate a bit of your expectation, what's `RC branches with same names`? Do you want to `only` list the 3 release/* branches but not have `develop` branch in the new pipeline?